# angular ui-router ui-view not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using angular with ui-view dependency but for some reason I can't get to show up my templateUrl.

this is my app.js it has my routes.

```
angular.module('starter', ['starter.controllers', 
'starter.services', 'ngStorage', 'ui.router'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

$stateProvider

```
.state('login',{
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'loginController'
})

})
```

my index.html

```
<body class="pace-top" ng-app="starter">
<!-- begin #page-loader -->
<div id="page-loader" class="fade in"><span class="spinner"></span></div>
<!-- end #page-loader -->

<!-- begin #page-container -->
<div id="page-container" class="fade">

<div ui-view></div>

</div>
<!-- end page container -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        App.init();
    });
</script>
```

this in inside the login.html. I want to load this template inside my index

```
<div class="login bg-black animated fadeInDown">
<!-- begin brand -->
<div class="login-header">
    <div class="brand">
        <span class="logo"></span> Color Admin
        <small>responsive bootstrap 3 admin template</small>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end brand -->
<div class="login-content">
    <form action="index.html" method="POST" class="margin-bottom-0">
        <div class="form-group m-b-20">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-b-20">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox m-b-20">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" /> Remember Me
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="login-buttons">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Sign me in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

i get no console errors.

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: do you have a `loginController` defined? if you refer to a controller that doesn't exist yet in your state, the sate will never finish initializing.

Comment: i did had my controller defined but i took it off and I put it back on and now is working. Weird but thanks anyway u point me to the right direction.